# CreateDrawerNavigator inside createStackNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

My issue is this: I can't seem to be able to add the hamburguer button on the left (to toggle the drawer) and also I cannot add the title to the drawer depending on the screen (for example, show 'Login' on header when it's on the login screen).

Brief explanation of the code:

The `AppNavigation.js` handles all the navigation for the app. Including the two drawers (`LoggedDrawer` and `UnloggedDrawer`).

They are inside a stack navigator (`RootNavigator`) and the `RootNavigator` is inside a container (react-navigation 3.0).

This is the code I have:

**AppNavigation.js**

```
const UnloggedDrawer = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
    SignUp: { screen: SignUpScreen }
  }, { 
  drawerWidth: SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.6 
  }
)

const LoggedDrawer = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen }
  }, {
  contentComponent: (props) => (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
        <DrawerItems {...props} />
        <Button
          color='red'
          title='Logout'
          onPress={() => { props.screenProps.logoutCurrentUser(props) }}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
  ),
  drawerWidth: SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.6,
})

const RootNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Init: {
    screen: Init,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
    },
  },
  UnloggedDrawer: { screen: UnloggedDrawer },
  LoggedDrawer: { screen: LoggedDrawer }
},
{
  mode: 'modal',
  title: 'Main',
  initialRouteName: 'Init',
  transitionConfig: noTransitionConfig,
})
```

**Init.js**

```
componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
  const { navigation } = props;
  if (props.userReducer.isSignedUp) {
    navigation.dispatch(StackActions.reset(
      { index: 0, key: null, actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'LoggedDrawer' })] }
    ))
  } else {
    navigation.dispatch(StackActions.reset(
      { index: 0, key: null, actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'UnloggedDrawer' })] }
    ))
  }
}
```

On my screens, I have a navigationOptions for all of them just like this (the only difference is the icon), this is only part of the code just as an example:

```
export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
  headerTitle: 'Home',
  drawerIcon: () => (
    <SimpleIcon
      name="home"
      color="rgba(110, 120, 170, 1)"
      size={20}
    />
  )};
}
```

So what I want to do is:

**1.** Add a hamburger icon to the header of all screens which will be used to toggle the drawer

**2.** Add the title on the middle of the header (also for all screens)

What I've tried:

- Everything I could find on the internet and nothing seems to work.

Also, if my architecture is wrong, please point that out, if also there's a different way to achieve what I'm trying to do it's also accepted.

Thanks in advance. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, answering my own question. 
What I want is easily achieved by using **react-native-elements**.

They have a component called 'Header' that you can use on each screen to customize the header.

I added this to both of drawerNavigators and the stackNavigator.

```
headerMode: 'null'
```

Then for each screen I had to wrap the JSX code in **React.Fragment**, so it went like this:

```
<React.Fragment>
  <Header
    statusBarProps={{ barStyle: 'light-content' }}
    barStyle="light-content"
    leftComponent={
      <SimpleIcon
        name="menu"
        color="#34495e"
        size={20}
      />
    }
    centerComponent={{ text: 'HOME', style: { color: '#34495e' } }}
    containerStyle={{
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      justifyContent: 'space-around',
    }}
  />
</React.Fragment>
```

Leaving the answer in case anyone else have the same issue.